# Three flexible (percentage) Columns in flexible Area

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I need to arrange three columns of divboxes with 33% width of the outer box, besides a fixed-width menu.

http://jsfiddle.net/uvw5c/1/

So i want the red, yellow, green area beides the orange menu, in ANY case of width of #menu.

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
       menu 
    </div>
    <div id="dialogbox">
        <div id="outer">
         <div class="inner" style="background-color:red;">
             col1
         </div>
         <div class="inner">
             col2
         </div>
         <div class="inner" style="background-color:green;">
             col3
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>

​  
#container{
   width:500px;   
   background-color:grey;
   height:300px;
}
#menu{
   width:300px; 
   float:left;
   height:100%;
    background-color:orange;
}

#dialogbox{  
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#outer{    
    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

.inner{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   width:33%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
​
```

​

Thanks in Advance for any hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this specific case you can do away with a lot of the markup and use `display: table;` and `table-cell;`. Set the width of the menu, and the others will automatically fill the rest equally.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="menu">
       menu 
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background-color:red;">
             test
    </div>
    <div class="inner">
             test
    </div>
    <div class="inner" style="background-color:green;">
             test
    </div>
</div>
​
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width:500px;
    display: table;
    height: 300px;    
}
#menu{
    width: 100px; 
    background: #00f;
    display: table-cell;
}

.inner{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100%;
    display: table-cell;        
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/uvw5c/5/

Comment: I like the way you go. But i have another requirement: If the space becomes to small, i have to break up the boxes (fluid) and this is not possible with table-cells :)

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately you're right. This is a good solution for those "need to fill remaining space" issues :)

Comment: Iam totally with you. Maybe you interested in my found solution few minutes ago, below on this site :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a div containing both the menu and the .inner elements.
Also check that width of inner must be 33.3% and 33.4% for one element (maybe the one in the middle)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution with the help of a friend:

http://jsfiddle.net/t39yV/2/

its very smart to use margin-left on the #dialogbox ;)

```
#container{
   width:100%;   
   background-color:grey;
   height:300px;
}
#menu{
   width:100px; 
   float:left;
   height:100%;
    background-color:orange;
}

#dialogbox{  
    margin-left:100px;
    height:100%;
}
#outer{    
    background-color:blue;
    height:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:100%;
}

.inner{
   padding:0;
   margin:0;
   width:33.3%;
    background-color:yellow;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```